# How do I add these two variables together into one of them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

So far what I have now is:

```
import random

#Character's stuff
w = 0
b = 0

#Earn
coinList = [100, 200, 350, 500, 1000]
x = random.choice(coinList)

y = 'You have collected ' + repr(x)
print(y)

int(input(w)) + int(input(x) = w
                    print(w)
```

However, whenever I try and run the code I am getting a syntax error on the "print(w)" part. I have also tried changing my code multiple times but I was unable to get any results. Please let me know if there is a way to fix this or if I need to change some big thing in the program.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment is incorrect, variable name goes to the left and and value/expression goes to The  right and print is bad indented (input() and int does not make sense here); using += operator to increment w by x

```
w += x
print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
w += x
print(w)
```